# texture coordinates in opengl es 2

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I have a png file with different sprites , in opengl 1. I have selected the picture with:

> // the png dimensions are 512x512
>
> gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_TEXTURE);
>
> //  x and y are the coordinates of the selected drawing
>
> gl.glTranslatef(x/512f, y/512f, 0);
>
> // w and h are the width and
>
> height of the selected drawing
>
> gl.glScalef(w/512f, h/512f, 0);

I have no idea in opengl2 , i read this tutorial:

http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-four-introducing-basic-texturing/

it is not difficult ,but you can only change the values of w and h (equivalent of

> gl.glScalef(w/512f, h/512f, 0);

)

Do any other tutorial or solution?

Comment: Would you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve, as it is not very clear from your question?

Comment: Sorry ,I do not understand your question .The problem is very simple , 1 file png with  some sprites that I want to draw with opengl2

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609423/applying-part-of-a-texture-sprite-sheet-texture-map-to-a-point-sprite-in-ios

Comment: Yes that should be what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So a tutorial you've read is what you need. Read previous tutorials from that website. The main difference in gles2 from gles1 is that all drawing happens inside shaders(fragment and vertex). Here is a part of texture bounding from my code and fragment shader source.

```
GLuint textureId;
// Generate a texture object
glGenTextures ( 1, textureId );
// Bind the texture object
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId );
/ Load the texture
glTexImage2D ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, where_you_store_unpacked_texture_data );

// Set the filtering mode
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameteri ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );

// Bind the texture
glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId );
```

Then after you have bound a texture, you can pass its id into fragment shader.

Fragment shader is something like this:

```
const char* pszFragShader_text = "\
        precision mediump float;\
        \
        varying       vec3  v_texCoord_text;\
        uniform  sampler2D  s_texture_text;\
        void main (void)\
        {\
            gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture_text, v_texCoord_text.xy );\
        }";
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I'll complete it a little later.